# Combining all nodejs microservices swagger links into a single swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a list of services all running in different ports and they are all individual microservices developed in nodejs. Each of the services have a swagger link developed for them. Is there any way we can combine all the swagger links into one and deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single entry point (e.g., a Composite API) for all of your API definitions like this:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: "My Composite API"
  version: "1.0.0"
paths:
  /my-service-1:
    $ref: "./my-service-1.yaml"
  /my-service-2:
    $ref: "./my-service-2.yaml"
  ...
```

You can deploy it in the same way that you would deploy any other Swagger definition.